# How to create a Dynamic Dropdown in React based on the value of Text Input box?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dropdown, react-dropdown-tree-select

I want a dropdown in react material ui project where the values of the dropdown change based on what i type into the search box, somewhat like the search box in npm homepage
[image]

I could not find something like that in Material Ui , and was wondering if there is something like that available

UPDATE: Although as mentioned in Answers React-Select was a great solution i  finally ended up using

Comment: https://github.com/krutik2403/react-searchable-select-mui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Creatable select.
[Link here](https://react-select.com/creatable)